# Creating an initialising an array of a reflected type in a single statement

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, vb.net, reflection

**Is it possible to create and initialise an array of a reflected type in .NET in a single statement?**

ie the equivalent of doing this, but using reflection:

```
var myArray = new String[] {"Test"};
```

I'm after an Array of a specific type, rather than an array of `object`.

Because Array lacks a constructor that can initialise values, I've been trying to use a generic `List`.  This is what I've got so far, which doesn't work (no matching constructor can be found):

C#:

```
var myArray = (Activator.CreateInstance(   typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string)),
                                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance
                                            |   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
                                            |   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
                                            |   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding,
                                            null,
                                            new[] {
                                                    (new[]   {Activator.CreateInstance( typeof(string),
                                                                                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance
                                                                                    |   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
                                                                                    |   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
                                                                                    |   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding,
                                                                                        null,
                                                                                        new[] { "Test".ToCharArray() },
                                                                                        null)
                                                            }).AsEnumerable()
                                                    },
                                            null));
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim myArray = Activator.CreateInstance(     GetType(List(Of)).MakeGenericType(GetType(String)),
                                                Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance _
                                            Or  Reflection.BindingFlags.Public _
                                            Or  Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance _
                                            Or  Reflection.BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding,
                                            Nothing,
                                            {
                                                {Activator.CreateInstance(  GetType(String),
                                                                            Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance _
                                                                        Or  Reflection.BindingFlags.Public _
                                                                        Or  Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance _
                                                                        Or  Reflection.BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding,
                                                                            Nothing,
                                                                            {"Test".ToCharArray()}, Nothing)
                                                }.AsEnumerable()
                                            },
                                            Nothing)
```

This question is asked out of curiosity about what is possible, rather than what should be done (as in I don't care if the solution is hideous, this is just for fun).  I'll happily accept answers for either language, if this is possible!

Comment: What line is the error on? oh, wait...

Comment: A simple way to create an array based on a type dynamically is via Array.CreateInstance: `Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), 1)`

Comment: @mikez: He is asking to create it an initialize it in one line.

Comment: It's confusing, because you are looking for the equivalent of an array initializer, but you create an instance of a generic List. If you add enough code you *may* end up with an array, but hardly the equivalent of {your statement + reflection}. Btw arrays don't have constructors so you may find it difficult to use Activator.CreateInstance

Comment: I'm aware that arrays do not have constructors, that's why I'm using a `List`!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<T>` have a constructor that accepts `IEnumerable<T>`, but you are passing an `IEnumerable<object>` to it. Hence why it failed with a `MissingMethodException`.

You simply need to replace the `.AsEnumerable()` with `.Cast<string>()`:

```
var myArray = (Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string)),
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding,
    null,
    new[] {
        (new[] { Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(string),
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance
        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding,
        null,
        new[] { "Test".ToCharArray() },
        null)}).Cast<string>()
    },
    null));
```

Edit: You can always cast it through reflection:

```
var myArray = (Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string)),
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding,
    null,
    new[]
    {
        typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast")
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string))
            .Invoke(null, new []
            {
                (new[] { Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(string),
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding,
                null,
                new[] { "Test".ToCharArray() },
                null)})
            })
    },
    null));
```

Comment: Unfortunately that call to `Cast()` does not make use of the reflected type (which for this example is `typeof(string)`, but it could be anything and known only at run-time!

Comment: I was kicking myself when I realised that I could have simply reflected the `Cast` method!  Fine work!

Comment: What a monstrosity we have created... And to make it complete, you can wrap the whole thing in a reflected `List<T>.ToArray()` call.

Comment: Indeed.  And in VB.NET, if you're riding with `Option Strict Off`, you can just put `ToArray()` on the end with the help of late binding!  I'm not sure which way is more horrible. :P

Comment: @Interminable You can do the same "hack" in C# too. `dynamic myArray = ...; myArray.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy enough with an array (like mike z's comment):

```
object entry = "Test";
Type type = typeof(string);

Array myArray = Array.CreateInstance(type, 1);
myArray.SetValue(entry, 0);
```

It creates an instance of `Length` one, and then sets the entry at index zero.

It is not easier with a `List<>`. You can do it like this:

```
object entry = "Test";
Type type = typeof(string);

object myList = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));
myList.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(myList, new object[] { entry, });
```

It creates an instance with the default constructor, and then acquires the `Add` method and invokes it with an argument "series" `{ entry, }`.

Using the `List<>` constructor overload that takes an argument called `collection` to initialize the `List<>` seems a bit circular. Because to use that, you must already have some "collection" of implementing `IEnumerable<string>` in advance, to create your `List<>` from.

Comment: It is of course easier if you do it with multiple statements, but I was asking how to do it as part of a single statement.

Comment: @Interminable But it makes no sense?! Is this code golf or something? You can create an object array and do the equivalent of `.Cast<T>().ToList<T>()` in one statement. It sucks and is ugly, but here you go: `var myList = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList").MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, new object[] { typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, new object[] { new object[] { entry, }, }), });`

Comment: I don't think this really qualifies as code golf.  My question was driven by curiosity as to whether something was possible (no matter how hideous). 
 As for the code in your comment, there's still the matter of getting the array itself.  I had a quick look but you can't seem to call `ToArray()` via reflection on the result of your code: `'Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.'`  It is of course possible that I don't know the correct way to invoke that method here, and I'm pretty tired right now so I may look again tomorrow.

Comment: Given any `object entry`, and a `Type type` which could come from `entry.GetType()`, the code from my first comment should be complete. I do not know what you are doing, but maybe you did not `MakeGenericMethod` on some method info representing `ToArray<>()` (it is a generic method). If, in the code from my comment, you replace `"ToList"` with `"ToArray"`, clearly you get an array.

Comment: ***Code***: `MethodInfo mi = asmType.GetMethod("GetDNComponents", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            string[] parameters = { dn };
            var test = mi.Invoke(null, parameters);`  How-to ***cast*** _test_ variable to private type ***System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Component[]*** or another "my" entity ?

Comment: @Kiquenet Probably the wrong place to ask, but I have the answer. You cannot really cast to a type which is `internal` to another assembly. Since their `Component` is a `struct`, you cannot even cast to `object[]` (since array covariance does not apply to value types). I suggest you do this: `var converted = ((Array)test).Cast<dynamic>().Select(x => Tuple.Create((string)x.Name, (string)x.Value)).ToArray();` Of course this needs `using` directives to `System` and `System.Linq`.

Comment: @Kiquenet OK, I am realizing that `dynamic` probably will maybe not let you read from an `internal` (to another assembly) type anyway. So you can use reflection instead. For example: `var converted = ((Array)test).Cast<object>().Select(x => { var t = x.GetType(); var name = t.GetField("Name").GetValue(x); var value = t.GetField("Value").GetValue(x); return Tuple.Create((string)name, (string)value); }).ToArray();`